# Tried loading a file in pig but this comesup everytime.Warning IMPLICIT_CAST_TO_FLOAT 2 time(s)

Tags: apache-pig

I am learning pig latin and this error keeps coming up.

command:
m = LOAD '/assignment/movies.csv' USING PigStorage(',')AS(id:int,name:chararray,year:int,rating:float,duration:int);

error msgs:
2021-01-11 21:10:44,303 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
2021-01-11 21:10:44,304 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2021-01-11 21:10:44,310 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.newplan.BaseOperatorPlan - Encountered Warning IMPLICIT_CAST_TO_FLOAT 2 time(s).

Answer (score 1):

These are just warnings, not errors, so your script will complete.

You could compare the effect of loading `rating` in as e.g. `chararray` and then using an explicit cast in a `FOREACH`:

```
cast_rating = FOREACH m GENERATE
    id..year,
    (float)rating AS rating,
    duration;
```